# OpenAS2 edict order to Woo order how?

Tags: woocommerce, edifact

we have successfully setup the OpenAS2 (https://github.com/OpenAS2/OpenAs2App)to send messages between our partners.
We are receiving orders from our partner in the EDI (edifact) format. Does anyone have an suggestion how to best translate this order and get it into our WooCommerce server as an order. Woo has an api to place orders:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order but not sure how to go from edifact order to Woo order. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

What programming languages are in your tech stack?  You need to convert the segments/elements into XML/JSON that the API requires.  EDI is just text formatted a specific way.  If you have Python, you might give BOTS a try.  There are a lot of open source parsers for EDIFACT.  Or, you could go the commercial translator route.

Comment: I am using ruby / rails

Comment: https://github.com/pvdvreede/edifact_parser - might not be rails, but you might be able to look @ the ruby code and port.

Comment: The `bots` library doesn't appear to have been updated in 8 years - however, an updated clone [edi-bots](https://github.com/eppye-bots/bots) is only... 3 years old... Hmm. @Andrew, do you have any experience in either library? Is there a real chance one still works? (without massive patches)

Comment: I've used it a long time ago.  I'd be pretty confident the edi-bots one should be fine. It's the same developer.